# Bind ComboBox to DataSet in code behind (no XAML)

Tags: c#, combobox, datatable

How to bind a Combo Box to DataSet in code behind, without using XAML at all:

I tried the following, but all my combobox items are "System.Data.DataRowView" instead of the actual value. What is wrong?

```
string str = @"SELECT * FROM FooTable";

da.SelectCommand = new SqlCeCommand(str, connection);
da.Fill(devDs, "FooTable");

dt = ds.Tables["FooTable"];

comboBox1.ItemsSource = devDt.DefaultView;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set `DisplayMemberPath` property

```
combobox.DisplayMemberPath = "ColumnName"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath` to set which column in your table should be used for UI presentation.

Test sample:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

dataTable.Rows.Add(1, "Test1");
dataTable.Rows.Add(2, "Test2");

comboBox1.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
```